# How to Select Tab in Internet Explorer Named href="#GST" using VBA excell

Tags: excel, vba, internet-explorer, browser-automation

I am doing automation of IE using VBA excel and I am not able to select on Tab href="#GST"

```
     <a role=”tab” aria-expanded=”true” 
aria-controls=”GST” 
href="#GST"jQuery110205664105838982267="18" 
data-toggle="tab" jQuery19103093133355326922="601">INVOICE / GST DETAILS</A>
```

Please help me out

Update I tried this solution

```
  Set HTML = ieApp.document 
HTML.querySelector("a[href='#GST']").Click
```

i tried few solutions but failed.

Comment: Always helps to post what you tried and describe exactly how it failed.

Comment: Hey Tim, I tried this solution but didn't worked  ---------------------         'Set HTML = ieApp.document

'HTML.querySelector("a[href='#GST']").Click

Comment: How did it fail? If you're getting an error then posting the actual error message helps.  Are you getting the HTML from "view source", or using the browser's developer tools?

Comment: I tried to test your sample code and I found that it is clicking the link fine without any issue. Here is the [Test Result](https://imgur.com/a/a7PALXe). With your above sample HTML, we are not able to produce the said issue. I suggest trying to provide a code that can reproduce the issue. It can help us to understand the issue in a better way and we can try to provide further suggestions to fix that issue. Thanks for your understanding.

Comment: @Tim, I got the code from inspect element and then DOM feature in internet explorer

Comment: Not much else we could suggest without a URL to test on.

Comment: If the URL is not public then you can try to develop a sample that can help us to produce the same issue. Then we can try to provide suggestions for it.

Comment: here is i am attaching image of error [Error Image](https://imgur.com/2nCEfCM)

Comment: Does replacing the "ieApp" with "IE" help you to fix the error? If yes, I suggest you please mark the helpful suggestion as an accepted answer. It can help other community members in the future in similar kinds of issues. Thanks for your understanding.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to check the picture of the error that you had posted in the comment.

[image]

You can see that error. It said that "**Object required**".

If you check your code, you can notice that throughout your code you are using "**IE**" as an object of the IE browser.

On the problematic line, you can notice that you are using "**ieApp**" as an object of the IE browser. You can see that "**ieApp**" object is not available in your code and that's why it is showing this error.

Maybe you found this code online but did not modify it properly.

To correct the issue, you need to replace the "**ieApp**" with "**IE**".

```
Set HTML = IE.document 
HTML.querySelector("a[href='#GST']").Click
```

It can help to fix this error.